# Нужна ли запятая перед "благодаря"?

Tags: пунктуация

Расположившись в центре Европы, родина Моцарта стала знаменитой благодаря горнолыжным курортам, зодчеству и обычаям, которые сохранились до наших дней, праздникам и песнопениям с танцами.

Comment: Думаю, чт*о* меня смущает в предложении... Нащупала: *и* перед *обычаям*. Эти "и обычаи" должны - в идеале - стоять в конце... Хорошо бы пересмотреть порядок всех соблазнов.

Answer (score 9):

В приведённом примере запятая не нужна - предлог с зависимыми словами стоит в конце предложения и не может быть отнесён к избыточно распространённым.

Оборот с предлогом *благодаря* обособляется, если требуется обозначить его границы во избежание двусмыслицы.

[У Розенталя](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/45.htm) это освещено в примечаниях к § 94:

> Деепричастные обороты не обособляются, если деепричастие утратило
>   глагольное значение; так, **простые отглагольные предлоги благодаря,
>   включая, исключая, кончая, начиная, считая, спустя и составные
>   отглагольные предлоги смотря по, судя по, невзирая на, несмотря на, не
>   доходя до, исходя из, начиная с вместе с относящимися к ним словами не
>   образуют деепричастных оборотов и не обособляются**.

[Грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach1/), цитируя "Русскую грамматику", рассказывает о факультативности обособления оборота в зависимости от степени его распространенности, близости к основной части предложения, порядка слов в предложении.

Обычно обособляются обороты, которые:

> а) располагаются между подлежащим и сказуемым;
>
> б) находятся не в начале и не в конце предложения;
>
> в) содержат объяснение того, о чем говорится в предложении, и
>   выделяются интонационно.
>
> В спорных случаях окончательное решение о постановке знаков препинания
>   принимает автор текста.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение.